# How can I track the progress of dd after I've already started it?

Tags: macos, terminal, hard-drive, data-transfer

I'm migrating my HDD to an external hard drive so that I can do a clean install of macOS Mojave.

**I'm using `dd if=/dev/disk02 of=/dev/disk15s2` to accomplish the task.**

**disk02** is the Macintosh HD (SATA-HDD), **disk15s2** is the WD External HD

I didn't realize that it wouldn't show me any indication of progress (the HDD has ~750GB on it) - this is the first time I've done this through the terminal.app in recovery mode. 

Is there a way for me to track the progress in another terminal window while it is in progress?

**I'm on a Macbook Pro mid-2012 running El Capitan.**

Comment: If you run this again, you should set the block size. dd if=/dev/disk02 of=/dev/disk15s2 bs=1024m will greatly improve the speed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, from a separate terminal you can issue this command:

```
kill -INFO 1234
```

where you need to replace 1234 with the pid of your dd process. You can look it up with the ps command.

Another simplification at a second terminal:

```
sudo kill -s siginfo $(pgrep ^dd)   # get dd info
```

Another simpler way is to request the progress information from the same terminal as `dd` by pressing Ctrl-T.

Comment: **Thank you, both of those work, Ctrl-T is definitely more effective**

Comment: I know his is the apple SE but it's one of the top results. on Linux it looks like there is no -INFO but at least GNU dd will respond to -USR1.

Comment: @SilentVoid On modern Linux you would normally start dd with the "status=progress" option, which gives you a nice progress bar.

Comment: @jksoegaard Right, but the question is what can you do if you've already started it and forgot or didn't know to put the progress option.